# Code working in Codepen but not in browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, sass

I have made a splash screen that works as intended, and can be seen on this codepen:

https://codepen.io/dbake3452/pen/VwmeoGa

However when I copied that code onto my project, the splash screen no longer goes away after 3 seconds. I'm thinking there is conflicting code somewhere, but I have not been able to spot it

My code:

```
'/ ///HTML


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.2/css/all.css" `enter code here`integrity="sha384-vSIIfh2YWi9wW0r9iZe7RJPrKwp6bG+s9QZMoITbCckVJqGCCRhc+ccxNcdpHuYu" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/kayportfolio.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/css/splide.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="container">

            <header>
                <nav>
                    <img id="bun" src="images/kay logo.png">
                </nav>
            </header>

            <div class="splash">
                <img class="fade-in" src="images/pippinhop.png">
            </div>

            <main>
                <i class="fas fa-caret-up"></i>
                <img id="myth" src="images/mythologyproj.png">
                <i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i>
                <img id="fingerguns" src="images/fingerguns.png">
            </main>

            <footer>
            </footer>

        </div>
        
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@splidejs/splide@latest/dist/js/splide.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/kayportfolio.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>



///SASS


$purple: #a9aaff;



body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 25vh 1fr 25vh;

    header {
        grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / -1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        img {
            width: 400px;
        }
    }

    .splash {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: $purple;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 2;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        img {
            width: 12.5%;
        }
    }

    .display-none {
        display: none;
    };

    @keyframes fadeIn{
        to {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }

    .fade-in {
        opacity: 0;
        animation: fadeIn 1s ease-in forwards;
    }

    main {
        grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / -1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        z-index: 1;

        i {
            font-size: 60px;
            margin: 20px;
            color: $purple;
        }

        i:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #myth {
            width: 800px;
        }

        #myth:hover {
            opacity: .5;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #fingerguns {
            width: 400px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 5%;
            top: 49%;
        }
    }

    footer {
        grid-area: 3 / 1 / 3 / -1;
    }
}




/// JS



const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
    splash.classList.add('display-none')
  }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: didi yuo tried it with css? maybe a compiling problem what are you using to compile your sass double check everything..

Comment: Better share a code sample as close as to your project. One issue could be that your .display-none class coming before your .splash class in your actual code.

Comment: Did my answer help you in some way? Consider giving feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sass has to be compiled to CSS for your browser to understand it, in VS code, there are handy extensions to require this, for example *live sass compiler*.

[image: live sass compiler]

Click the watch sass button on the bottom (or compile in any way you want).
[image: watch sass]

You can see that the compiler added the CSS version to the project.

[image: css version]

Now just include the CSS file in your html, for example (if CSS file is in the same folder):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" >
```

Don't forget to put your JS code in `<script></script>` tags as well, or create a separate file and include it.

```html
<script>
  const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      splash.classList.add('display-none')
    }, 3000);
  });
</script>
```